# How can I check if a dependency exists in a remote repository?

Tags: java, maven

I tried with `dependency:get` or `dependency:copy`, but those goals will also resolve from my local repo.

Next I tried to make a simple download from `https://repo.company.com/repo/<path-to-group>/<artifactId>/<version>/<artifactId>-<version>.pom`, but that fails because of missing permissions. I guess that's why I tried to use a plugin, in order to use the existing maven credentials.

Context: Writing a deployment script that should avoid overwriting existing artifacts in our company repo.

Comment: Your company repo can probably be configured to refuse overwrite in the 1st place

Comment: @GaëlJ true, i will look into that as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be `dependency:get`, but overriding the local repository on command line with an empty (temporary) directory.

But, as was already said, Artifactory and Nexus are usually configured in a way that they do not override existing artifacts.

local repo override: `-Dmaven.repo.local=...`

Comment: how do you override the local repo on the command line?